# Opencv Code for anti-flickering in video sequence captured by a moving camera

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video

I am working on anti-flickering of a video sequence capture by a moving camera.
I am able to do for static camera, where i am calculating the moving average of 5 frames , but when i try to do the above method for video sequence capture by moving camera (camera placed on top of CAR) , I am getting blured images. Can anyone help me on this .

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this issue ?

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this issue ?